# How does one have a python interpreter with its own tab in vscode (in the integrated terminal)?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

In the bottom window of vs code there is a debug console problmes output terminal:

[image]

I want to have one for my python intepreter. Is that possible?

I know I can open another terminal option but that is not what I am looking for but its what I am doing for now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not super happy with my current hacky solution but for now this is what I am doing:

- click `shift + enter` on any line. That runs the command in the python shell.
- Then do control+`, that sends your cursor to the python shell terminal
- now you can try commands on python.

I really wanted just a tab of its own like debug consule that had python working all the time and I could go to it with a keyboard short cut but I guess this work for now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the run option from right top.
[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4ANb.png) to execute.

or simply click on terminal and enter python or python3 (depends on version installed on your machine)

Comment: I am doing the second one currently. I guess what I want to do is just have a terminal whenever I want to try some quick python. Perhaps what you suggest is to click on that and that would lead me automatically to a python shell? I guess that would be better than what I had in mind cuz it would not involve mouse clicks...

Comment: Okay. At the right side of the terminal, bash is showing. click on bash there will be select default shell option and add python as default.

Comment: Glad i could help! Best way to express gratitude in this sight is with upvotes and keeping discussions technical in the comments section, another gift from me ;)

Comment: I really want to upvote but i don't have 15 reputations.